# React/Redux - how to pass in value from redux store into a function inside of onClick handler

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component in which I have a function that renders a list of locations via the `FieldsArray` from redux and I'm trying to figure out how I can access a property known as `_id` when the `initialValues` are set from the parent component?

Here is my function that renders the list:

```
renderLocations({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed } }) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className={styles.contactInfoSection}>
            <h2>Locations</h2>
            <div>
              <button type="button" className={styles.add} onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add Location</button>
              {(touched || submitFailed) && error && <span>{error}</span>}
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul className={styles.locationsList}>
            {fields.map((location, index) =>
              <li className={styles.locationCard} key={index}>
                <div>
                  <Field
                    name={`${location}.street`}
                    hintText="Street"
                    component={TextField}
                    label="Street"/>
                  <Field
                    name={`${location}.city`}
                    hintText="City"
                    component={TextField}
                    label="City"/>
                  <Field
                    name={`${location}.state`}
                    hintText="State"
                    component={TextField}
                    label="State"/>
                  <Field
                    name={`${location}.zip`}
                    hintText="Zip"
                    component={TextField}
                    label="Zip"/>
                </div>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  title="Remove"
                  onClick={() => {
                    fields.remove(index);
                    this.removeLocation(<locationId?>); // I need to be able to pass in an _id from the initialValues here
                  }}>Remove</button>
              </li>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

And then for reference:

```
<ManageCustomerForm
   initialValues={this.state.customer} />
```

`this.state.customer` has a `locations` property that maps to an array of objects that contain the `_id` for the location, along with some other data.

Comment: if the parent is passing the state then doesn't the child component have to access that through `props`?

Comment: can you show the structure of objects in locations array ?